# Does no one use display: block and inline-block?

Tags: html, css

This might be a weird question but on youtube in guides I always see people using flex and grid.

I've started learning them but prior to that I was using block and inline-block exclusively.

So do people use flex and grid only?

And also is flex different from flexbox because vs code displays them as 2 different options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I generally use `display: block` when a element with `display: none` has to be made visible.

Also, paragraphs and spans are inline elements. I find it quite difficult to work with inline elements, so whenever I style them, I generally make them block elements (may be not if they are children of a grid).

But in case of containers, yes I normally use `display: grid`. And they are generally have default display value of `block`, so why change it to block again?

As far as flex and flexbox go, I don't know much about flexbox. But as far as I know, flex is the improved version of `display: box` and `display: flexbox`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to code css for others to see such as in a professional context, the safe bet is most often flex or grid, but they all have their uses in different contexts. My suggestion to you would be to go into the inspector on some of your favorite websites and see what they use. It you like one way better than the other or find one way more understandable, then use that one, otherwise, just use both.